# how to indicate to ext4 the size of a file before doing the write?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

I'm curious if there is a way to do this?  my understanding of ext4 is limited, but I do believe it has the capability to allocate contiguous ranges of disk space

I'm writing a file, from RAM, and know its size before the open().  Is there a way I can indicate this to the filesystem?  are there performance benefits?

Comment: The write to disk could happen much later (e.g. after program exits), unless you do `sync` or `fsyncdata` syscalls.

Comment: gotcha,  I'm mostly interested in pushing out the 'extents'.  I believe ext4 assumes an 8k or greater write (shortening during the flush).  if my file is 8k however there might be an opportunity for some perf gains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for [posix_fallocate](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_fallocate.html).

Using this allows the filesystem to allocate blocks up-front, which can reduce the fragmentation of the file. In particular, this matters for applications that randomly write chunks of the file (think bittorrent clients). For an application that writes a file sequentially, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Considering that `posifx_fallocate()` is just one syscall similar to `fseek()` I think apps should call it every time the final filesize is already known before starting to write into file. That will allow the kernel to optimize the disk handling and space allocation.